# Blender renders are too low poly

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image: When in rendered view]

[image: When in material view]
Could someone please explain how I make the objects higher poly like in the material view, because when rendering them they come out very low poly.

Comment: Maybe check the Render level if you've given a Subdivision Surface modifier?

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: Have you given a Subdivision Surface modifier to your object? Check its Render value. Or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Object silhouettes looks lowly on both images ... so I'm guessing there is not any subdivision at all. Lower image looks high-poly probably just thanks to shader (bump or normal map) in combination with current light condition.